# Firebase authentication (is not a function, is not a constructor)

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-authentication

I don't know what is wrong. I'm using Node.js and trying to log in using email/password and Google authentication. I have enabled all of them in Firebase console.

npm Firebase version - 3.1.0

part of code:

```
var firebase = require('firebase');

var config = {
  apiKey: "AIzaSyAH27JhfgCQfGmoGTdv_VaGIaX4P-qAs_A",
  authDomain: "pgs-intern.firebaseapp.com",
  databaseURL: "https://pgs-intern.firebaseio.com",
  storageBucket: "pgs-intern.appspot.com",
};

firebase.initializeApp(config);

app.post('/login', function(req, res) {
  var auth = firebase.auth();

  firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(req.body.login, req.body.password).catch(function(error) {
    // Handle Errors here.
    var errorCode = error.code;
    var errorMessage = error.message;
    // ...
  });
}
```

Error: firebase.auth(...).signInWithLoginAndPassword is not a function
or
Error: firebase.auth(...).GoogleAuthProviders is not a constructor when I write

```
firebase.auth().signInWithPopup(provider).then(function(result) {
  // This gives you a Google Access Token. You can use it to access the Google API.
  var token = result.credential.accessToken;
  // The signed-in user info.
  var user = result.user;
  // ...
}).catch(function(error) {
  // Handle Errors here.
  var errorCode = error.code;
  var errorMessage = error.message;
  // The email of the user's account used.
  var email = error.email;
  // The firebase.auth.AuthCredential type that was used.
  var credential = error.credential;
  // ...
});
```

I just did exactly what is in documentation.

Comment: I have found a work-around for this using anonymous user authentication from the client side. Kindly elaborate your use case, so that I could write an answer based on that.

Answer (score 1):

Your first error probably comes from a typo somewhere.

`firebase.auth(...).signInWithLoginAndPassword is not a function`

Notice it says signInWith**Login**AndPassword, the function is called signInWith**Email**AndPassword. In the posted code it's used correctly, so it's probably somewhere else.

`firebase.auth(...).GoogleAuthProviders is not a constructor`

You have not posted the code where you use this, but I assume this error happens when you create your `provider` variable, that you use in `firebase.auth().signInWithPopup(provider)`

That line should be `var provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();`

Based on the error message, I think you might be doing `new firebase.auth().GoogleAuthProvider();` Omit the brackets after auth, if that's the case.

Comment: Sorry, but I wrote these errors manually. In fact I had signInEmailAndPassword and there is still the problem. I omitted these brackets and problem still exists.

Comment: What is the actual error message then? I can help better if you post exactly what error you're getting, and also the code where it originates from, otherwise I'm guessing blindly.

Comment: ```Type Error: firebase.auth(...).signInWithEmailAndPassword``` at line where is ```  firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(req.body.login, req.body.password).catch(function(error) {
    // Handle Errors here.
    var errorCode = error.code;
    var errorMessage = error.message;
    // ...
  });``` Without brackets there is the same error but without (...)

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to sign your node.js app into firebase with email+password or one of the social providers.

Server-side processes instead sign into Firebase using so-called service accounts. The crucial difference is in the way you initialize the app:

```
var admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp({
  serviceAccount: "path/to/serviceAccountCredentials.json",
  databaseURL: "https://databaseName.firebaseio.com"
});
```

See this page of the [Firebase documentation for details on setting up a server-side process](https://firebase.google.com/docs/server/setup).

Comment: `The 'serviceAccount' property specified in the first argument to initializeApp() is deprecated and will be removed in the next major version. You should instead use the 'firebase-admin' package. See https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup for details on how to get started.`

Comment: I don't understand why you reference https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup when it is using `admin` for all the calls

Comment: The variable name can be anything, as long as it matches between the `require` call and the other calls. That said: I modified it to match the current docs.

Answer (score 1):

Do not call GoogleAuthProvider via an Auth() function.

According to the documentation you have to create an instance of GoogleAuthProvider.

`let provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider()`

Please check the following link https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/google-signin